# Trying to replace characters in C++ Strings, completely stuck

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am a novice on a good day and I am trying to input several strings, and then replace only a few of them with the letter "x" so as to censor them when they are displayed back on screen. I know my problem is simple in my gut, but I am so stuck and I need some help. I looked around for this answer but didn't find anything I could use. Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name, userName, securityNumber, password;
    string str1, str2, str3;
    string x = "x";

    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter your Social Security Number: ";
    cin >> securityNumber;
    cout << "Enter your username: ";
    cin >> userName;
    cout << "Enter your password: ";
    cin >> password;


        {
        securityNumber.replace(0, 99, x);
        password.replace(0, 99, x);

        str1 = name + " " + securityNumber;
        str2 = userName + " " + password;

        str3 = str1 + " " + str2;
        }

    cout << "Your information: " << str3 << endl;

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might as well just say `securityNumber = password = x;` then.

Answer (score 2):

```
securityNumber.replace(0, 99, x);
```

There are many different overloads of `std::string::replace()`. You are calling the

```
std::string& replace (size_t pos,  size_t len,  const std::string& str);
```

version; this replaces the portion of the input string from `pos` to `pos+len` with `str`. So, in this case, the first 99 characters in `securityNumber` are being replaced by a single "x".

I'm pretty sure this isn't what you're after. Is the goal to replace every character in `securityNumber` with an `x`? Or just numeric digits? In the first case, it would probably just be easier to construct a new string filled with an appropriate number of `x`s, for example:

```
 securityNumber = std::string(securityNumber.length(), 'x');
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you would want to permanently replace the strings entered by the user.

What you probably want to do is:

```
// make a temporary display string of size same as that of securityNumber with all characters 'x'
std::string tempDisplay( securityNumber.size(), 'x' );
str1 = name + " " + tempDisplay;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use replace and the same string you came in with you can use 
`securityNumber.replace(securityNumber.begin(), securityNumber.end(), securityNumber.size() , 'x');`
for example that will take a string of any length and then replace its contents with x characters.

Answer (score 0):

You have good answers here, however you can do this in this way too,you could just use this code snippet, if let's say you want to replace all **a** chars with **x** :

```
for(int i = 0;i < SecurityNumber.length;i++)
   if(SecurityNumber[i] == 'a')
      SecurityNumber[i] = 'x';
```